# How can i link my start button to process all the functions on my bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Pardon me if i don't expatiate with clarity, i am still new to this.. working on a uni project and The aim of the GUI App is to automate login into multiple accounts..

When the start button is clicked, i want it to take the filename and run it through starter and begin to login. however when ii have tried it has given me this error.

```
" Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Loginsam() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'usr' and 'pas'"

#step1. Load filename from samfiles.

def open():
    global filename
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/user/local/desktop", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("Txt","*.txt"),("allfiles", "*.*")))
    filename= root.filename

    my_label = Label(root, text=root.filename)
    my_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)
    #my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    #my_image_label = Label(image=my_image).pack()
 #       configfile.Insert(INSERT, f.read())



Load_File = Button(root, text="open File", command=open)
Load_File.grid(row=1, column=0)

#

#Process the file in step one in here


def Starter():
    while True:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line.strip()
            print('line{:3d}: {}'.format(i, line))

            if len(line) > 0:

                data, _= line.split('#')
                usr, pas = data.split(':')
                usr = usr.strip()
                pas = pas.strip()

                print('line {:3d} usr: {}'.format(i,usr))
                print('line {:3d} pas: {}'.format(i, pas))

                #Loginsam(usr, pas)


#step4. Link to all the previous functions


Start= Button(root, text="Start", command= Loginsam)
Start.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

#End result login in successfully

def Loginsam(usr, pas):

    chromedriver_path = r"C:/"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    sam = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)
    sam.maximize_window()
    sleep(2)
    sam.get('url')
    sleep(3)

    user = sam.find_element_by_name("username")
    user.clear()
    user.send_keys(usr)
    sleep(3)

    password = sam.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.send_keys(pas)
    sleep(6)


root.mainloop()
```

I would be grateful if someone could give me a solution to this..

Comment: You've posted way more code than is necessary, and you didn't post the code that is causing the error.  Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. The error seems pretty self-explanatory, `Loginbot` requires arguments and you aren't passing them in.

Comment: ***`TypeError: Loginsam() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'usr' and 'pas'"`***: You have defined: `def Loginsam(usr, pas):`. You call: `command= Loginsam`

Comment: Thank you for responding @BryanOakley, i meant to put `Loginsam` , and i want it to take the data,( usr and pas) from the uploaded text file. in the file dialog.

Comment: @stovfl how do i solve it, when i run it without the buttons it works perfectly however the `def Starter():` function, is defined as: `def open():`

Comment: @5tilln3w ***"how do i solve it"***: Depends **where** you have `(usr, pas)` assigned and if the vaiables are accessible. ReadTheFineTutorial: [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: The indentation of the posted code needs fixing. Indentation is critically important in python, and we only have the posted code to go by.

Comment: @BryanOakley i know however posting it on here i was getting indentation errors.

Comment: is there a method to linking the starter function to open function?

Comment: Posting code with proper indentation isn't difficult. Paste the code with proper indentation, select it, click the `{}` button.

Comment: @BryanOakley i think i sorted it is that better?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code the funciton `Loginsam` requires two parameters: `usr` and `pas`. WHen you call the the function from the command in the `Start` button it is called without parameters

```
Start= Button(root, text="Start", command= Loginsam)
Start.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
```

To solve you have to run the command using `lambda`

```
username = 'MY USERNAME'
password = 'MY PASSWORD'
Start= Button(root, text="Start", command= lambda usr=username, pas=password: Loginsam(usr, pas))
Start.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: Your approach will not work, because the OP can't access the local variable `usr` and `pas` from `def Starter():`. **Don't change the conditions from a question.**.